Push all dependencies to a private python package index
I am building my own python package and uploading it to a private python package index using devpi.
At the moment, I am installing my package this way:
pip install --index-url <my-index-url> --extra-index-url <pypi-index>.
The reason I am using the --extra-index-url is that my Python package depends on publicly available python packages e.g. NumPy. My challenge is that, nowadays, there is a (new) publicly available package whose name conflicts with mine, and the `pip install´ command is trying to install the publicly available version of the package.

How can I tackle this issue? My current thinking is that I should upload all project dependencies to my private repository and get rid of the --extra-index-url but I am not sure how to do that. My package has a setup.py.


I always recommend against --extra-index-url for exaclty this reason. It is useful until it isn't. For small temporary workarounds it can be helpful to use the extra index URL option, but this always breaks sooner or later. -- It is best to always have one and only one package index server. The difficulty is in configuring your package index server so that it serves you exactly the packages you need from the sources you need. I do not know how to do it with devpi, I also do not know if devpi can do this. -- I know simpleindex can help.

Just rename your private package, so that there is no conflict. (Or at least, pick a much later version number and require that newer version, so that the "old" public package never gets chosen over your "new" private version.)
